# Update node's physicsbody with texture animation?

Tags: sprite-kit, textures, skphysicsbody

What is the best approach to handle texture animations which are different to the default  texture size and thus a node's physicsbody?

How performant is it to update a physicsbody with an animation (and back afterwards)?

For example once the player initiated a slide, the physicbody would be updated once and whenever the slide is finished the physicsbody is set back to its default erect size.

Is there a more efficient way?